# Как обработать исключение "Типы данных text и varchar в операторе equal to несовместимы."?

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой вот код на языке C#

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vin = VIN2.Text;
        string strana = Strana.Text;
        string model = Model.Text;
        string baza = Baza.Text;
        string kuzov = Kuzov.Text;
        string dvigatel = Dvigatel.Text;
        string transmissia = Transmissia.Text;
        string god = God_vipuska.Text;
        string zavod = Otdelenie_zavoda.Text;
        string nomer = Poryadkoviy_nomer.Text;
        SqlConnection sQLite = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LAPTOP-KJLU9H2F\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = 'Автосалон'; Integrated Security = True");
        sQLite.Open();
        var command = sQLite.CreateCommand();
        string test = @"SELECT * FROM VIN_номер WHERE VIN_номер = '@VIN' OR Регион_Страна_Фирма_расшифровка = '@Страна' OR Модель_расшифровка = '@Модель' OR Колесная_база_расшифровка = '@База' OR Тип_кузова_расшифровка = '@Кузов' OR Двигатель_расшифровка = '@Двигатель' OR Тип_трансмиссии_расшифровка = '@Коробка' OR Год_выпуска_расшифровка = '@Год' OR Отделение_завода_расшифровка = '@Год' OR Порядковый_номер = '@Номер'";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("VIN", vin);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Страна", strana);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Модель", model);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("База", baza);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Кузов", kuzov);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Двигатель", dvigatel);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Коробка", transmissia);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Год", god);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Завод", zavod);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Номер", nomer);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(test, sQLite);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

И при порогоне вылазит вот такое исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обработать это исключение?

Comment: его не надо обрабатывать, надо просто найти где именно ты сравниваешь текст и варчар и сделать там одинаковые типы

Comment: Хорошо, но мне sql server не дает задать первичный ключ к нужному столбцу, как через запрос это сделать?

Comment: а какая связь ошибки со сравнением разных типов и задачей первичного ключа?

Comment: А такая, что в таблице у меня было varchar, а в коде text, и я решил изменить в таблице varchar на text, но sql server против

Comment: а почему в коде было не поменять? Почему не привести их к одному типу при сравнении например?

Comment: Никогда не используйте метод `AddWithValue`: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Используйте метод `Add` с явным указанием типа `SqlDbType`.

Comment: Параметры в запросе не нужно заключать в одинарные кавычки: `'@VIN'`. Уберите их у всех параметров.

Comment: Вот мне интересно: почему так упорно создают и заполняют `DataSet`, когда запрашивают данные из одной таблицы? И далее используют один `DataTable`. Почему бы сразу не создать и заполнить `DataTable`?

Comment: Покажите скрипт создания таблицы: `create table ...`. Будем посмотреть, какие там у вас типы.

Comment: Не, я лучше буду сам разбираться Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Единственное только что хотел уточнить:

Comment: как задавать тип данных nvachar правильно? вот так ? command.Parameters.Add("VIN", SqlDbType.NVarChar(20, 0).Value = VIN.Text;

Comment: ну если ты попробуешь, то получишь ошибку скорее всего. просто указываешь тип и все

Comment: Ну вот я получил исключение "Ошибка преобразования значения varchar "@Заказ" в тип данных int." Вот здесь
 command.Parameters.Add("Заказ", SqlDbType.Int);

Comment: что-то у тебя все в кучу смешалось. Смотри какие типы у тебя описаны и такие и передавай в качестве параметров.

Comment: ну у меня у ячейки, к которой я обращаюсь тип данных int, переменную я тоже привел к типу int, откуда там вообще взялось varchar

Comment: @АндрейПавлов, очевидно в таблице у тебя varchar ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯